# Convert Selenium WebDriver code to JMeter WebDriver Sampler code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Hi I want to use selenium chromedriver code in JMeter webdriver sampler.
Below is selenium code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
```

How can I convert above code and use in JMeter webdriver sampler

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code and tweak it according to your need:-

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
WDS.browser.executeScript('window.open("http://blazemeter.com");')
var handles = WDS.browser.getWindowHandles()
var iterator = handles.iterator()
var counter = 1;
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
   var handle = iterator.next()
   WDS.browser.switchTo().window(handle)
   WDS.log.info('Window ' + counter + ' title = ' + WDS.browser.getTitle())
   counter++;
}
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

For more information:-https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered

Comment: Could you please help me .. How to wait for some time in JMeter WebDriver Sampler?

Comment: Please search this line in the link provided above. var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5)...This should help to implmement wait. Import the required jar as show in the blog. Also, please vote and accept, if it helped.